# Why is this Java Switch statement not able to progress?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I've been practising Java programming and recently thought I'd try my hand at some State based scripting using a different Library. I've hit a snag with a switch statement that I can't seem to get to the second case. Now I understand you guys might not be familiar with the external API but I just wondered if it was something wrong with my logic in general. The States come from an enum and I have a getState() method that tests for different prerequisites:

```
 private enum State {

    CUT, WALK_TO_BANK, BANK, WALK_TO_TREE

}

private State getState() {
    if (client.getInventory().isFull() && !BANK_AREA.contains(myPlayer()))
        return State.WALK_TO_BANK;
    if (!client.getInventory().isFull() && !CHOP_AREA.contains(myPlayer()))
        return State.WALK_TO_TREE;
    if (!client.getInventory().isEmpty() && BANK_AREA.contains(myPlayer()))
        return State.BANK;
    return State.CUT;
}
```

Switch statement:

```
switch (getState()) {
        case CUT:
            if (!myPlayer().isAnimating() && equipmentTab.isWieldingWeapon(Axe)) {
                log("You have an Axe.");
            } else {
                log("You don't have an axe");
                State.WALK_TO_BANK.equals(true);
                RS2Object bank = closestObjectForName("Bank Booth");
                if (bank != null) {
                    if (bank.interact("Bank")) {
                        while (!client.getBank().isOpen())
                            sleep(250);
                        client.getBank().withdraw1(Axe);
                        equipmentTab.equipForNameThatContains(EquipmentSlot.WEAPON, "axe");
                        State.CUT.equals(true);
                    }
                    RS2Object tree = closestObject(TREE_ID);
                    if (!myPlayer().isInArea(CHOP_AREA) && client.getInventory().isEmpty()) {
                        State.WALK_TO_TREE.equals(true);
                    }
                    if (tree != null) {
                        if (tree.interact("Chop down"))
                            sleep(random(1000, 1500));
                        log("Trying to cut tree");
                    }
                    break;

                    case WALK_TO_BANK:        // IDE states- Unable to resolve symbol
                        status = "Walk to Bank";
                        traversePath(path, true);
                        sleep(random(1500, 2500));
                        break;
                    case WALK_TO_TREE:
                        status = "Walk to Tree";
                        if (!myPlayer().isInArea(CHOP_AREA) || client.getInventory().isEmpty() && equipmentTab.isWieldingWeapon(Axe)) {
                            log("You have an Axe.");
                            State.WALK_TO_TREE.equals(true);
                        }
                        traversePath(path, false);
                        sleep(random(1500, 2500));
                        break;

                    case BANK:
                        status = "Banking";
                        RS2Object bank = closestObjectForName("Bank booth");
                        if (bank != null) {
                            if (bank.interact("Bank")) {
                                while (!client.getBank().isOpen())
                                    sleep(250);
                                client.getBank().depositAll();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return random(200, 300);
            }
```

After the CUT case finishes and moves on to the WALK_TO_BANK case, IntelliJ indicates that it cannot resolve the symbol. I'm not quite sure why.. I am quite new to this so my code won't be as efficient as it could be but this just some practice at scripting and obviously from this, I'll improve.

Comment: You missed a brace `}` to close the `else` statement in `CUT` case that should go before the `break`.

Comment: This actually made the code runnable, I missed out 2 of them :/. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that if you let your IDE format your code, that sort of thing is usually clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off. Your `case` statements all have to be in the same scope -- outside of the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Test
{
    private enum State {

        CUT, WALK_TO_BANK, BANK, WALK_TO_TREE

    }

    int step = 0;

    private State getState()
    {

        if (step == 1)
            return State.WALK_TO_BANK;
        if (step == 2)
            return State.WALK_TO_TREE;
        if (step == 3)
            return State.BANK;
        return State.CUT;

    }

    Test()
    {
        switch (getState())
        {
            case CUT:
                if (true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
                break;

            case WALK_TO_BANK: // IDE states- Unable to resolve symbol
                break;
            case WALK_TO_TREE:
                break;

            case BANK:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```